# Php does not store dynamically added extra input fields data

Tags: php, database, forms, dynamic, input

i had following html code for add more input fields to my form, but when i submit form database does not store extra fields data, i got only first field data.

**HTML**

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="course_article[article_title]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
 $(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="course_article[article_title]' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});

</script>
```

**PHP**

```
    if (isset($this->request->post['course_article'])) {
                $this->data['course_articles'] = $this->request->post['course_article'];
            } else {
                $this->data['course_articles'] = '';
            }

**Store to databse**
if (isset($data['course_article'])) {
            foreach ($data['course_article'] as $course_article) {
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "course_article SET course_id = '" . (int)$course_id . "', article_title = '" . $this->db->escape($course_article['article_title']) . "'");
            }
        }
```

i don't know what goes error here, any help.?
thanks

Comment: A fiddle for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/9k53f/

Answer (score 1):

Both in HTML and js add a `[]` in name like this `name="course_article[article_title]"` should be `name="course_article[article_title][]"`

Answer (score 1):

When you add an input field to the form, you add a number to the name attribute, like so:

```
name="course_article[article_title]2"
```

This is invalid,

Try posting the fields as an array:

```
 name="course_article[article_title][]"
```

As you post, you can use this in your PHP:

```
 foreach($_POST['article_title'] as $article){
     //Do something with each title
 }
```